# Change position of a Flutter Snackbar below Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, flutter, snackbar

Can i show Snackbar below Bottom Navigation Bar ?

what i want :

[image: [snackbar below navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRce7.png)]

reality :

[image: [snackbar above navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnLiE.png)]

Any reply is appreciated :)
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the bottom navigation bar is referred to as the BottomNavigationBar used inside Scaffold class, and snackbar is the [SnackBar class](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars), I believe it is hard to achieve. This is because the SnackBar is like an overlay on the screen and the bottomnav class can't tell whether a snackbar is shown or not. Also moving the bottomnav up and down accordingly with the snackbar is a challenge itself.

If I wanted to create what you want, I'd do something like this. I'll creat a custom snackbar-like widget. This widget is structured like this

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Hallo"),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text("Hello"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    CustomSnackBarLikeWidget(),
  ],
);
```

the CustomSnackBarLikeWidget() is normally not shown (height is 0) making the scaffold use the whole screen height thus the bottomnav sticking to the bottom. In cases when the CustomSnackBarLikeWidget() is shown, it has some sort of contents (some height) and will shove the bottomnav upwards, like [snackbar below navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRce7.png)

the CustomSnackBarLikeWidget() will also be a complicated widget. This widget will constantly be watching if you have called this widget to show any snackbar contents.

I don't know if my answer helps but feel free to ask me questions.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply :) i've already succeed to make the stream subscription, but i always failed to make the CustomSnackbarLikeWidget because i want to make it at app file ( stack with materialApp ), i always get error 'media query not found' , any suggestion ?

Comment: Oh you have done the hard part already nice!
The CustomSnackBarLikeWidget does not have to be outside the material app.

Comment: Can you include the code? (the code where you get the media query not found is ok!)

Comment: after trying again, i already get the result i want :)
my mistake is i put the CustomSnackbarLikeWidget above the materialApp, thank you so much

Comment: happy to hear that!

Comment: bro im still facing this issue..can yu helpe me?